# Pandas multi column mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame, and would like to get column wise `mean()` 
as below.

```
    A    B    C      D
1   10  100 1000    10000
2   20  200 2000    20000
3   30  300 3000    30000
4   40  400 4000    40000
5   50  500 5000    50000
```

Answer:

```
  A    B      C      D
  30  300   3000    30000
```

Please suggest a way to do it.
I have tried `df.mean()` and other variations of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) with [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
print (df.mean().to_frame().T)
      A      B       C        D
0  30.0  300.0  3000.0  30000.0
```

Or:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df.mean().values.reshape(1,-1), columns=df.columns))
      A      B       C        D
0  30.0  300.0  3000.0  30000.0
```

Or:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(np.mean(df.values, axis=0).reshape(1,-1), columns=df.columns))
      A      B       C        D
0  30.0  300.0  3000.0  30000.0
```

Comment: Glad can help, nice day!